# Multi-region image segmentation based on pixel intensities

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am attempting to segment a grayscale image into three regions based on its pixel intensities. Due to illumination and specks, this task turns out to be more challenging than I expected...

Here is the **original image**:

[image: Original image]

The bright area occupies most of the image. Below it, there is a gray area, and the black area takes up a narrow portion at the bottom of the image.

Multi-Otsu thresholding was not very effective as the histogram does not show sharp peaks...

```py
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu

thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(image)
plt.hist(image.ravel(), bins=255)
for thresh in thresholds:
    plt.axvline(thresh, color='r')
```

[image: histogram]

```py
regions = np.digitize(image, bins=thresholds)
plt.imshow(regions, cmap='jet')
```

[image: Multi-Otsu thresholding]

I think what I need is something like a large-scale adaptive thresholding with multiple labels, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

## EDIT

Applying blurring before thresholding showed more promising result.

```py
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (0, 0), 8)

thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(blur)
regions = np.digitize(blur, bins=thresholds)
plt.imshow(regions, cmap='jet')
```

[image: blurring and thresholding]

But the boundary between "white" and "gray" regions in `x > 1100` is still inaccurate.

Meanwhile, applying Sobel filter to the blurred image returns kinda accurate boundaries.

```py
grad_x = cv2.Sobel(blur, cv2.CV_16S, 1, 0, ksize=3)
grad_y = cv2.Sobel(blur, cv2.CV_16S, 0, 1, ksize=3)
abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_x)
abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_y)
grad = cv2.addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0)
plt.imshow(grad, cmap="gray")
```

[image: sobel]

So the question becomes: **How can I combine the Sobel result and the Otsu result to acquire accurate mask?**

## EDIT2

Sorry I didn't add the manual mask. Here are the boundaries I have in mind, which are somewhat similar to the Sobel result:

[image: manually created boundary]

The red boundary is almost linear in this example, but it can possibly have more complicated shape such as:

[image: artificial boundary]

### More context

This image shows a porous material getting wet with liquid. The region beneath the yellow boundary is the bulk fluid, and the area between the red and yellow boundaries is the wetted region.

Therefore, the red boundary is always above the yellow boundary, and it continuously spans across the image.

I think the best approach would be to combine this morphological knowledge with pixel intensity gradient, but I can't come up with how to achieve this.

Comment: That sounds to me like elbow method or silhouette thresholding... (it's beeng a few months since I don't do CV, will need to refresh)

Comment: Consider adding tags for `opencv` and `image-processing` and `scikit-image` to attract the right folks.

Comment: don't expect perfection. the "gray" part has a serious gradient. perhaps show us a labeling of this that you made manually. -- lowpass the image, multi-otsu then. you might have to set those thresholds manually (my suggestion: 60, 160).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for a thorough response, but here's one suggestion: if you can assume that the boundaries are straight lines, I suggest sobel -> hough transform to find the lines, then draw the lines as black boundaries on a white binary image, then label connected components.

Comment: OP says about `np.digitize`: "the boundary [...] is still inaccurate" and has not elaborated since. I've asked for a reference segmentation, manually created, so we all can understand what OP has in mind *precisely*. -- you need to realize that, as soon as you post a bounty, you will attract people that are only here for the rep.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry. I added more elaboration.

Comment: there is potential for improved image acquisition. does wetted material appear reflective? does it present differently under some light (incidence angle) and viewing angle? what accounts for the wetted area being darker on the left side than the right? what are the blurry spots on the material? are we looking at a flat surface of this material? is it parallel to the camera, or tilted? the bottom edge, going from material to water, looks fuzzy. what accounts for this? what does this experimental setup look like from a human perspective? we've seen the apparatus (camera) perspective so far

Comment: We're seeing through a glass wall, and the surface of the material is perpendicular to the line of sight of camera. The fuzzy edge and blurry spots are because of the fluid meniscus and tiny droplets around the contact line.
I appreciate your suggestion, but I'm more curious about image analysis methods that can deal with current image, rather than improving the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

How about using k-means clustering? If necessary, you can apply a smoothing filter before clustering. Below, I'm using the same smoothing filter you used before clustering. I'm not sure if I'm addressing your real requirement for using sobel and otsu. Just wanted to propose another possible way to segment it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('input.png')

img = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (0, 0), 8)

Z = img.reshape((-1,3))
# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)
# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 3
ret,label,center=cv.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

cv.imwrite('output.png', res2)
```

segmented:
[image: out]